# Request traffic incident data by country?

Tags: here-api

I want traffic incident data for all incidents within a countries borders. Is there a way to request traffic incident data by country?

Or alternatively select a region with the bbox parameter but exclude results from neighbouring countries? i.e. use bbox coordinates to fully encompass Sweden but exclude results from Finland, Norway and Denmark.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `negBBox` parameter which restricts the response to an area outside of the specified bounding box.

```
https://traffic.ls.hereapi.com/traffic/6.3/incidents.xml
?bbox=48.8379,8.4375;50.7364,9.84375
&apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}
&negBBox=37.5000,126.9700;37.4900,126.9800
&status=active
&maxresults=50
```

Answer (score 0):

As documented in https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/dev_guide/topics/resource-parameters-incidents.html, there request param called `tables` can be used for filtering country specific data as it is possible multiple countries data will be included at cross border requests.